# The result of else command not working

Tags: shell-script, scripting

This script works.

```
$cat list

IP address=192.3.xx.xx
IP address=192.4.xx.xx
IP address=192.19.xx.xx
IP address=192.22.xx.xx
```

```
$ cat myscript.sh

for i in `cat list | cut -d= -f2  | egrep '192.3|192.4'`
do
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
       echo $i
    else
       echo "no IP found"
    fi
done
```

```
$ ./myscript.sh

192.3.xx.xx
192.4.xx.xx
```

but if change the 192.3 and 192.4 to something else like 192.8,  I should  get:

```
no IP found
```

The script is returning with nothing.

I appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process. See https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: You'll also get matches on addresses such as `192.168.37.7` because you have not bounded the `3` in `192.168.3`

Comment: Thanks Chris , I fixed the typo.
If I can get the else command to return with a value like 
no IP found
that will be great.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone.  
Please let me know if there is a way to show appreciation. 
Like positive feedback, etc.
I am new to this

Comment: Shahriar: see the help center (circled questionmark at right of the topbar) including ["What should I do when someone answers my question"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

So, if you have `cat list | cut -d= -f2  | egrep '192.8'`, the output of `egrep` is empty, and the command substitution expands to nothing. The `for` loop will have zero items to loop over, and the loop body will not run, and there's nothing to print the "not found" message.

Not that the test against `$?` at the start of the loop body makes that much sense anyway. True, you're testing for the exit status of the command substitution in the first iteration, but on the latter ones, you're testing for the exit status of the *last command of the previous iteration*, with isn't likely to be too useful. Not that the `echo` there would be likely to fail, but if you're doing something else, you might get funny results.

```
for i in `cat list | cut -d= -f2  | egrep '192.3|192.4'`
do
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
       # assume we're doing something more useful here
       echo "trying to do something with $i..."
       # but it happens to fail
       false
    else
       echo "no IP found"
    fi
done
```

the output is

```
trying to do something with 192.3.xx.xx...
no IP found
```

A bit confusing.

---

The simple way to have an "or else" section that runs if the loop doesn't find anything, is to just set a flag in the loop and test for that later, like so:

```
found=
key=192.8
for i in $(cat list | cut -d= -f2  | egrep "$key"); do
    found=1
    echo $i;
done
if [ -z "$found" ]; then
    echo nothing found
fi
```

Though in this case, that's still a bit silly since what the `for` loop essentially does, is to just print the same thing that `egrep` already printed, item by item (plus you're relying on word splitting working correctly, but you probably don't have glob characters there anyway).

I suppose you might be doing something else with the IP addresses, but if you're just going to print them, you might as well just use the output from `egrep` directly and check the exit status to see if it matched anything:

```
key=192.8
if ! cat list | cut -d= -f2  | egrep "$key"; then
    echo "nothing found"
fi
```

---

Alternatively, read the output lines into an array and work on that. In Bash, you'd use `readarray` for that:

```
readarray -t ips < <(cat list | cut -d= -f2  | egrep "$key")
num=${#ips[@]}
if [ "$num" = 0 ]; then
    echo "zero items in list"
else 
    echo "found $num items"
fi
for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
    echo "doing something with $ip..."
done
```

Not much different from the split+for loop, but safer for cases where the input elements themselves might contain whitespace or glob characters.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your help.  I am trying your suggestions.
One quick question, what is the best UNIX command to convert the list like
cat list 
192.xx.xx.xx

Comment: thanks so much everyone for your help, I am trying those.
One quick question.  If cat list looks like
192.xx.xx.xx
192.xx.yy.zz
192.xx.ww.qq
How do I make it look like 
cat list
192.xx.xx.xx, 192.xx.yy.zz, 192.xx.ww.qq
IN other words, have the list in one, added a comma in between.

Answer (score 2):

The mandatory POSIX tool (i.e. available on all Unix boxes) for general manipulation of text is `awk`. Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'=' '$2 ~ /^192\.[34]\./{f=1; print $2} END{ if (!f) print "no IP found"; exit !f }' list
192.3.xx.xx
192.4.xx.xx
```

```
$ awk -F'=' '$2 ~ /^192\.[8]\./{f=1; print $2} END{ if (!f) print "no IP found"; exit !f }' list
no IP found
```

A few other things worth mentioning:

- `egrep` was deprecated almost 20 years ago in favor of `grep -E`, don't use it.
- I don't think you understood @ChrisDavies' comment as the problem [he
  pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/764771/the-result-of-else-command-not-working/764852#comment1458230_764771) is still present in your question.
- `cat list | cut -d= -f2` is a [UUOC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award), it should be `cut -d= -f2 list` or `cut -d= -f2 < list` or, if you prefer, `<list cut -d= -f2`.
- `echo $i` should be `echo "$i"` (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).
- Always run your code through http://shellcheck.net until you get a lot more familiar with shell.